# How to integrate service now with Datastage?

Tags: integration, servicenow, datastage

I want to develop a job to integrate service now in data stage using REST API.To raise the ticket automatically in SNOW. How can I do that ?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.stages.xml.core.usage.doc/topics/examples_reststep.html

Comment: You can create make REST calls in ServiceNow in System Web Services > Outbound > REST Messages.